# When does Chapel pass by reference and when by constant?

Tags: pass-by-reference, chapel

I am looking for examples of Chapel passing by reference.  This example works but it seems like bad form since I am "returning" the input.  Does this waste memory?  Is there an explicit way to operate on a class?

```
class PowerPuffGirl {
  var secretIngredients: [1..0] string;
}

var bubbles = new PowerPuffGirl();
bubbles.secretIngredients.push_back("sugar");
bubbles.secretIngredients.push_back("spice");
bubbles.secretIngredients.push_back("everything nice");

writeln(bubbles.secretIngredients);

proc kickAss(b: PowerPuffGirl) {
  b.secretIngredients.push_back("Chemical X");
  return b;
}

bubbles = kickAss(bubbles);
writeln(bubbles.secretIngredients);
```

And it produces the output

```
sugar spice everything nice
sugar spice everything nice Chemical X
```

What is the most efficient way to use a function to modify Bubbles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether Chapel passes an argument by reference or not can be controlled by the argument intent. For example, integers normally pass by value but we can pass one by reference:

```
proc increment(ref x:int) { // 'ref' here is an argument intent
  x += 1;
}
var x:int = 5;
increment(x);
writeln(x);                 // outputs 6
```

The way that a type passes when you don't specify an argument is known as the default intent. Chapel passes records, domains, and arrays by reference by default; but of these only arrays are modifiable inside the function. ( Records and domains pass by **`const ref`** - meaning they are passed by reference but that the function they are passed to cannot modify them. Arrays pass by **`ref`** or **`const ref`** depending upon what the function does with them - see [**array default intent**](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/language/evolution.html#array-default-intent) ).

Now, to your question specifically, class instances pass by "value" by default, but Chapel considers the "value" of a class instance to be a pointer. That means that instead of allowing a field (say) to be mutated, passing a class instance by `ref` just means that it could be replaced with a different class instance. There isn't currently a way to say that a class instance's fields should not be modifiable in the function (other than making them to be explicitly immutable data types).

Given all of that, I don't see any inefficiencies with the code sample you provided in the question. In particular, here:

```
proc kickAss(b: PowerPuffGirl) {
  b.secretIngredients.push_back("Chemical X");
  return b;
}
```

the argument accepting `b` will receive a copy of the pointer to the instance and the `return b` will return a copy of that pointer. The contents of the instance (in particular the `secretIngredients` array) will remain stored where it was and won't be copied in the process.

One more thing:

> This example works but it seems like bad form since I am "returning" the input.

As I said, this isn't really a problem for class instances or integers. What about an array?

```
proc identity(A) {
  return A;
} 
var A:[1..100] int;
writeln(identity(A));
```

In this example, the `return A` in `identity()` actually does **cause a copy** of the array to be made. That copy wasn't created when passing the array in to `identity()`, since the array was passed by with a **`const ref`** intent. But, since the function returns something "by value" that was a reference, it's necessary to copy it as part of returning. See also [**arrays return by value by default**](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/language/evolution.html#readme-evolution-arrays-return-by-value) in the language evolution document.

In any case, if one wants to return an array by reference, it's possible to do so with the **`ref`** or **`const ref`** return intent, e.g.:

```
proc refIdentity(ref arg) ref {
  return arg;
}
var B:[1..10] int;
writeln(refIdentity(B));
```

Now there is no copy of the array and everything is just referring to the same `B`.

Note though that it's currently possible to write programs that return a reference to a variable that no longer exists. The compiler includes some checking in that area but it's not complete. Hopefully improvements in that area are coming soon.